# How do I turn a file of my Minecraft world into .schematic?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm a big player of an assortment of games. And I want to build a super cool map from Hypixel using Schematica. I have Schematica functionally installed, but I want to turn my world file that I have of my world into a .schematic so I can use it in Schematica.

How do I do that exactly?